# spring boot junit test with spring-data-jpa and MockMvc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa, mockmvc

I'm writting some test code.
I use spring-boot 1.5.9.RELEASE.

this is my test code

```
@Test
public void shouldUpdateUserName() throws JsonProcessingException, Exception {
    for(UserDto.Request request: userRequests) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(request.getName());
        user.setCity(cityRepository.findTopByName(request.getCity()));

        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    UserDto.Request sample = userRequests.get(new Random().nextInt(count));
    User sampleUser = userRepository.findTopByName(sample.getName());

    String userNameAfterUpdate = sampleUser.getName() + Thread.currentThread().getName();

    UserDto.Request request = new UserDto.Request();
    request.setCity(sampleUser.getCity().getName());
    request.setName(userNameAfterUpdate);

    mockMvc.perform(put("/user/" + sampleUser.getId())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request)))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    assertNotEquals(sampleUser.getName(), userRepository.findOne(sampleUser.getId()).getName());
    assertEquals(userNameAfterUpdate, userRepository.findOne(sampleUser.getId()).getName());
}
```

at sampleUser. i find and get an user object.
and at mockMvc.perform(). i find and user by id and update it.

but i get same object. and mockMvc updates sampleUser object.
so test assertNotEquals fails.

how cant it happened?
please someone help.

Comment: can you provide additional information as to where you might be using transactions, @Transactional, as well as your datasource in general?

Answer (score 0):

This is an effect of transactions. You load your use in one transaction (T1).

You then via MockMvc perform another transaction (T2) changing the user.

But your test is still in transaction T1 and won't see the changes. Actually due to the behavior of JPA, it wouldn't even access the database but just pull it from the entity manager.

There is no easy way to "fix" this in the test. 
Instead, I'd recommend splitting your tests in two or more individual tests:

One test verifying your MVC setup, ensuring the correct method is called and the expected HTTP status code and content is returned.

A separate test ensuring that the method actually does the expected changes to your entity and calls the repository.

Both tests should arguably use a mocked repository.